# How do I sort the a list, ascending, by the date?

Tags: python, list, sorting, date

I have a list made up of two part sublist:

```
my_list = [["10/15/2018", "John"], ["10/12/2019", "Beth"], ["9/15/2018", "Cory"]]
```

I need list sorted by date in ascending order and printed, line by line.

I know `list.sort()` doesn't produce the correct order. I tried to use datetime.strptime but can't get that to work with out an error message.

```
def display_by_date(list):

    list.sort(key=lambda x: 
      datetime.datetime.strptime(x['Created'], '%m %d %Y'))

      for entry in list:
        print(entry)

display_by_date(my_list)
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying a sort `key` with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
from datetime import datetime

my_list = [["10/15/2018", "John"], ["10/12/2019", "Beth"], ["9/15/2018", "Cory"]]

print(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], '%m/%d/%Y')))
# [['9/15/2018', 'Cory'], ['10/15/2018', 'John'], ['10/12/2019', 'Beth']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [["10/15/2018", "John"], ["10/12/2019", "Beth"], ["9/15/2018", "Cory"], ["10/11/2019", "Carl"]]

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x[0], format='%m/%d/%Y'))
```

and gives:

```
[['9/15/2018', 'Cory'],
 ['10/15/2018', 'John'],
 ['10/11/2019', 'Carl'],
 ['10/12/2019', 'Beth']]
```